# OpsMgr SDK Service Event ID 26219 - SCOM 2022

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, system-center, reporting, scom

Every 5 minutes, the following log generates twice in the Operations Manager logs on the Management Server. It's definitely related to the reporting services. I uninstalled the reporting services entirely and deleted the database in SQL. Re-install everything and configure new DBs for the reporting services. Still generates this event log.

```
An exception was thrown while processing GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser for session ID uuid:658fd6bc-f3e1-4201-b906-69dd3950a759;id=647.
 Exception message: Value does not fall within the expected range.
 Full Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Interop.Security.Auth.IAzApplication2.InitializeClientContextFromStringSid(String SidString, Int32 lOptions, Object varReserved)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Mom.Sdk.Authorization.AzManHelper.GetScopedRoleAssignmentsForUser(Int32 operationNumericId, String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Mom.Sdk.Authorization.AuthManager.GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser(Guid operationId, String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Mom.Sdk.Authorization.AuthorizationService.GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser(Guid operationId, String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ServiceDataLayer.SecurityConfigurationService.GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser(Guid operationId, String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Mom.ServiceDataLayer.SdkDataAccessBackCompatProxy.GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser(Guid operationId, String userName)
```

The event view will also show event ID 26328 and 26329 for the Data Reader account and Action Account. The Session ID seems to point to the Data Reader account. The Data Reader account is assigned the Operations Manager Report Operators Role and Operations Manager Report Security Administrators.

Currently in the console, there is no alert. But before the re-install, I would also get an alert that it couldn't connect to \ssrs

I'm not sure what exactly triggers the alert. It's not the event. Any help to solve this is appreciated. I haven't found anything concrete searching online.

SSRS: Instance cannot connect to SSRS Report Manager

```
Instance cannot connect to SSRS Report Manager.
PortalStatusCode: 200
Portal Error Message: 
Http Status Code: 
REST Status Code: 500
REST Service Error Message:
```

SSRS: Instance cannot connect to SSRS web service

```
Instance cannot connect to the SSRS web service.
PortalStatusCode: 500
Portal Error Message: An error occurred when invoking the authorization extension. (rsAuthorizationExtensionError)
Value does not fall within the expected range.
Http Status Code: 
REST Status Code: 0
REST Service Error Message:
```

Additional logs from reporting services:

```
library!ReportServer_0-1!24d4!06/17/2022-17:16:04:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!24d4!06/17/2022-17:16:04:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AuthorizationExtensionException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AuthorizationExtensionException: An error occurred when invoking the authorization extension. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Value does not fall within the expected range.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.ISecuritySpaceDataAccess.GetUserRolesForOperationAndUser(Guid operationId, String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Reporting.Security.ManagementGroupConnection.GetReportingUser(String userName)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Reporting.Security.GroupAuthorization.CheckAccess(String userName, Byte\[\] secDesc, RequiredOperation requiredOperation) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Security.<>c\_\_DisplayClass21.<CheckAccess>b\_\_1e()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionBoundary.Invoke(Method m) - 
   -- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Comment: Great job! I've been looking for a solution to this issue as well. The Operations Manager event log is now really clean with basically only informational events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out after spending days on the issue. Turning on the Report Server HTTP Log allowed me to see what was happening.

```
06/17/2022 22:36:05 127.0.0.1 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 127.0.0.1 20480 localhost GET /ReportServer  500 189 938 1.1 - - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1432 94 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1454 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1454 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1454 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1468 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1467 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1467 47 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1467 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1463 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1465 47 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> <DataReaderAccount> <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  200 1486 31 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 367 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - - 
06/17/2022 22:36:05 <ManagementServer> - <ReportServer> 47873 <Site> POST /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx  401 421 0 1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000) - - -
```

It seems the SQL Server Reporting Services Management Pack was using the Local System Action Account. Once I realized this, I was able to make the appropriate changes so it would use the Data Reader account to determine if SSRS was available or not. I wish the following was mentioned as needing to be configured in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/reporting-services-management-pack-changes-history?view=sc-om-2022). If it's mentioned anywhere, I didn't see it.

- Go to **Administration** --> **Run As Configuration** --> **Profiles**
- Search for Microsoft SQL Server Monitoring Run As Profile
- Add a Run As account

  - Account Name: Data Warehouse Report Deployment Account
  - A selected class, group or object: Object

    - Look for: MSSQL Reporting Services: Instance (Native Mode)
    - Filter by:
    - Add the appropriate available item
    - click ok and save

As soon as I did this, all the alerts and events went away in the console.